# lua metatable registration from c question

Tags: lua

Hello I have the following bit of code which seems to work, but I'm not sure why - I've built a testclass as follows

```
class testclass {
    int ivalue;
public:
    int getivalue();
    void setivalue(int &v);
};
```

and then registered the testclass (bits left out for the actual functions but they're pretty basic). It's the registration of the metatables I'm not following. (etivalue and setivalue are c functions that call the class functions of the same name)

```
static const struct luaL_Reg arraylib_f [] = {
    {"new", new_testclass},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

static const struct luaL_Reg arraylib_m [] = {
    {"set", setivalue},
    {"get", getivalue},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

int luaopen_testclass (lua_State *L) {
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "LuaBook.testclass");
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1); /* duplicates the metatable */
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    luaL_register(L, NULL, arraylib_m);
    luaL_register(L, "testclass", arraylib_f);
    return 1;
}
```

The bit I don't understand is I'm adding the functions to the __index for the metatable but
when I run

```
a = testclass.new()
a:set(10)
print(a:get())
```

Then it works as expected. The bit I don't understand is why the set is being called when I think I've loaded it in the __index metatable? Is that what I've done or something else?

tia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int luaopen_testclass (lua_State *L) {
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "LuaBook.testclass"); //leaves new metatable on the stack
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1); // there are two 'copies' of the metatable on the stack
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index"); // pop one of those copies and assign it to
                                    // __index field od the 1st metatable
    luaL_register(L, NULL, arraylib_m); // register functions in the metatable
    luaL_register(L, "testclass", arraylib_f);
    return 1;
}
```

That code is equivalent to the example Lua code:

```
metatable = {}
metatable.__index = metatable
metatable.set = function() --[[ stuff --]] end
metatable.get = function() --[[ stuff --]] end
```

I assume that 'new_testclass' C function sets the metatable "LuaBook.testclass" for the returned table.

In your code you dont add functions to the metatable __index field. You assign pointer to metatable to that metatable's field named __index, and you register set and get functions to it.

Now, if you set that metatable to the value returned from 'new_testclass' function  (which I assume you do) - lets call that value 'foo', and you call foo:set(10), than Lua:

1. checks that there is no such field as 'set' in 'foo'
2. sees that 'foo' has a metatable
3. looks at that metatable's __index field - sees it's a table
4. checks if that table assigned to __index field has a field 'set' and it's value is a function
5. calls 'set' method passing 'foo' as self parameter

I hope that this will help you figure out whats going on here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you are asking how the `set()` `get()` get invoked through the `__index` metamethod.

The code can be expressed in pure lua:

```
local o = {}

function o.get(self)
    return self.ivalue
end

function o.set(self, val)
    self.ivalue = val
end

a = {}
mt = {
    __index = function(t, n)
        return o[n]
    end
}

setmetatable(a, mt)

print(a:get())
a:set(10)
print(a:get())
```

results:

```
nil
10
```

In this example the `mt` table is set as the `a` table's metatable.  The `__index` metamethod is invoked for both `get` and `set` since neither `get` or `set` currently exist in table `a`.

If this example is changed instead to this:

```
local o = {}

function o.get(self)
    return self.ivalue
end

function o.set(self, val)
    self.ivalue = val
end

a = {}

function a.get(self)
    print('here')
    return self.ivalue
end

mt = {
    __index = function(t, n)
        return o[n]
    end
}

setmetatable(a, mt)

print(a:get())
a:set(10)
print(a:get())
```

results:

```
here
nil
here
10
```

In this case the `__index` metamethod is **NOT** invoked for `get()` since a `get` index already exists in the `a` table.

Many interesting constructs can be created using metamethods, once you understand how they work.  I suggest reading [13.4.1 - The __index Metamethod in PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html) and work through a few more examples.  All of the above can also be done from the *c api*.